# Capture element based on previous text using XPath

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get a `<p>` element by its previous text. Example:

```
<div>
    Header:
    <p>ITEM</p>
    ID:
    <p>123</p>
    Title:
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```

where I want to capture "123". I've tried a couple of combinations of preceding-sibling but haven't been able to get it.

`.//p[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::text()][.='ID:']]`

`.//p[preceding-sibling::text()='ID:']`

I don't have control over the HTML and they don't want to change it. I will always know the text before the paragraph I want to capture. Is this possible?

Edit: added more to the example. The element to grab won't always be the first/last item to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//p[preceding-sibling::node()[1][normalize-space()='ID:']
```

will select all `p` elements whose *immediately* preceding sibling has a space-normalized string value of `ID:`.

**Notes:**

- Your first try was close but failed to account for the whitespace surrounding `ID:`.
- Your second try additionally failed to account for the immediacy constraint.

Answer (score 1):

This `XPath` give the `123` text after the node containing `ID`:

```
(//div[contains(text(), "ID:")]/p)[1]
```

Comment: This seems to just get the first paragraph in the div. ID won't always be the first element. I will update my example